# Flex Combobox Binding Issues

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, air

In my application i used combobox and adding value using dataprovider like

```
   id="teamComboBox" dataProvider="{xml_teamcoupon.lastResult.coupon.teamcoupon_name}
```

my xml like this

```
<pick15>
<coupon>
<teamcoupon_id>1</teamcoupon_id>
<teamcoupon_name>teamcoupon1</teamcoupon_name>
coupon></pick15>
```

so comobobox shows team coupon name . But what i want, ifi  choose team coupon name then Correspond teamcoupon id how can i get . i trid `teamComboBox.selectedItem.teamcoupon_id` but shows error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind to the coupon element, rather than the `teamcoupon_name` element, and then use the `labelField` attribute of the combobox to reference `teamcoupon_name`.

```
<mx:ComboBox dataProvider="{xml_teamcoupon.lastResult.coupon}" labelField="teamcoupon_name" />
```

Now, you can get the currently selected element using `combobox.selectedItem`, and the id by referencing `combobox.selectedItem.teamcoupon_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the id node is on the same level as the name node, you'll need to reference the parent node first.

Something like:

```
teamComboBox.selectedItem.parent().teamcoupon_id
```

Comment: Thank you so much Christophe Herreman . i tired it's also working